# Multilanguage setup breaking View results layouts

Tags: i18n-l10n

**Background:**

We're trying to setup multilanguage options on our site (to allow English/Welsh options). We're using the Internationalization module primarily, with the language detection set to URL.

**The problem:**

The static content pages work fine, but when a page containing views is translated it seems to break the order and div styling of the Views results.

Any ideas what might be causing this (e.g. have I missed a setting in the Block/View somewhere to apply a div style to the translated version of the page)?

E.g. see below - in pic 2, the results are wrongly shown single column rather than in a 4 column grid, and are displayed *before* the rest of the main content rather than *after*):

**Comparison of default (www.../resources) and translated (www.../cy/resources) page layouts**

[image: Default page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to an error in the logic of a custom template not taking in to account variable languages.